# How to solve the nonlinear differential equation $- f'' = f^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve the following differential equation

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f = f^3$$

with initial conditions $f'(0) = f'_0$ and $f(0) = f_0$.

My approach considers $v = \frac{d}{dx}f$. Hence, one finds $v^2 = \frac{f^4}{3} + C_1$ i.e. $(\frac{d}{dx} f)^2 = \frac{f^4}{3} + C_1$. There must have a simple way to solve the former or ther latter equation. I thank in advance.

Comment: Letting $\sqrt{}$ denote the positive branch of the square root, consider the two equations:
$$
f' = \pm \sqrt{f^4 / 3 + C}.
$$
Each equation can be handled by the [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: The ODE in the question and the ODE in the title are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f = f^3$$
$(\frac{d}{dx} f)^2 = \frac{f^4}{3} + C_1\quad$ is false.

The correct calculus is :
$$f''f' = f^3f'$$
$$\frac12 (f')^2 = \frac14 f^4+\text{constant}$$
$$f'=\pm\sqrt{\frac12 f^4+c_1}$$
$$x=\pm\int \frac{df}{\sqrt{\frac12 f^4+c_1}}+c_2$$
This integral involves the elliptic function of the first kind.

The inverse function $f(x)$ involves a Jacobi elliptic function.